# Update minimum value based on consecutive values using SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Trying to update the minimum `CardSerial` into the column `MinimumCardSerial`. Below is my table structure.

```
CardID      CardSerial       Denomination Minimumcardserial
----------- ---------------  ------------ -----------------
2685680     214026002        10           
2685681     214026003        10           
2685682     214026004        10           
2685778     214026100        10           
2685779     214026101        10           
2685780     214026102        10           
2685878     214026200        10           
2685879     214026201        10           
2685880     214026202        10
```

Expective below result

```
CardID      CardSerial       Minimumcardserial
----------- ---------------- ----------- ------------ -------------
2685680     214026002        214026002
2685681     214026003        214026002
2685682     214026004        214026002
2685778     214026100        214026100
2685779     214026101        214026100
2685780     214026102        214026100
2685878     214026200        214026200
2685879     214026201        214026200
2685880     214026202        214026200
```

The below query useful to find the minimum cardserial based on consecutive group, however trying to find a update query to update the minimum cardserial into the source table itself. Can some one help in this please.

```sql
WITH
  sequenced AS 
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Denomination ORDER BY cardSerial) AS sequence_id,
    *   FROM  Cards )

SELECT
  min(cardSerial),  Denomination
FROM   Sequenced
GROUP BY
  Denomination, 
  cardSerial - sequence_id
ORDER BY
  Denomination, 
  cardSerial - sequence_id
```

Comment: I've removed [[tag:sql-query-store]] as it doesn't appear relevant here, unless you can elaborate why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a type of gaps and islands problem.  Assuming that `cardserial` is a number, you can subtract an enumerated value -- and that difference is constant for incrementing values.

Then just take the minimum over that grouping:

```
select c.*,
       min(cardserial) over (partition by cardserial - seqnum) as minimum_cardserial
from (select c.*,
             row_number() over (order by cardserial) as seqnum
      from cards c
     ) c;
```

If `cardserial` is not a number, you can just convert to numeric:

```
min(cardserial) over (partition by convert(numeric(38), cardserial)) - seqnum)
```